# Localization in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, localization

I wanted to localize strings in my application (that is built using objective JavaScript and html5). I came across - MVC JavaScript localization of external .js files, http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/blog/2010/12/01/javascript-string-localization-done-right/ etc. But which would be the best way to do it?

Mine is a huge app with frequent change in strings. So I am looking for a stable, easy to adapt solution.

Please suggest!

Thanks 
Sneha

Comment: We already use something like you posted. It works well

Comment: how about : https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/#readme? Is it good..? any idea?

Comment: Looks interesting but runs a lot of script.

Comment: What templating language are you using? Is your app exclusively front-end, or does it have a backend?

Comment: Don't take my word as gospel!

Comment: If your application is pure client side, then look at [SVG edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/)'s approach available in its `locale/locale.js` module. Very unobtrusive.

Answer (score 0):

I think [L20n](http://l20n.org/) by Mozilla is quite awesome!